# image_tag in helper not passing options to view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## The Problem

I have a helper method that runs a ternary operation.  The result operands are both image_tag methods.  When I call this helper from a view, the ":size" option does not get converted into height and width tags in the html.  When I copy and paste either image_tag method directly into my view file, everything works fine.

#### application_helper.rb

```
def display_portrait(candidate)
  if candidate.portrait_url
    image_tag(candidate.portrait_url.to_s, :size => "10x10")
  else
    image_tag("missing_portrait.png", :size => "10x10")
  end
end
```

#### view.html.erb

```
<%= display_portrait candidate %> DOES NOT GENERATE HEIGHT AND WITH ATTR'S

<%= image_tag("missing_portrait.png", :size => "10x10") %> DOES GENERATE ATTR'S
```

The helper still generates an  anchor with the correct source; it only lacks the height and width attributes.

Thanks for taking a moment to help,

Michael

Comment: IF you have found the answer mark it or if you haven't state it.

Comment: Haven't found the answer yet.  Thanks for the help so far.  I will use your debugging method to dig into it a little more when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

First check by write puts statement in display portrait method if condition then check what is

coming in params of this method.

you can also do this in views

```
   <%= image_tag(@image.portrait.url(:thumb):alt => "Description") %>
```

Hope it will help you......

Answer (score 0):

**application_helper.rb**

```
def display_portrait(candidate)
  if candidate == 1
    image_tag(candidate, :size => "10x10")
  else
    image_tag("missing_portrait.png", :size => "10x10")
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

In this view,

```
<%= display_portrait 1 %>
```

generates,

```
<img alt="1" height="10" src="/assets/1" width="10" />
```

and

```
<%= display_portrait 0 %>
```

generates,

```
<img alt="Missing_portrait" height="10" src="/assets/missing_portrait.png" width="10" />
```

There must be something wrong in your If condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use 'size' in any case if I were you unless you don't care about IE<9. I'd rather use a style property.

PS: For this problem in particular, I would try to use width: and height: to see if that changes anything. I know some helpers in Rails have different behaviour depending from where they are called.